# Are there two groups of charges associated in an alternating current half wave?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electric-current, antennas

Edit: to better express the problem:

As alternating current passes along a wire:

- Individual current charges produce a magnetic field after zig zagging rapidly locally with a small resultant vector. The magnetic fields sum together.
- Different charges are pushed to the surface in response to the current charges and form an excess electric field, leaving the interior wire neutral.

Question:
Is this view correct?

[image]

Additional:
The half wave dipole antennas shown at [Dipole antenna - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Half-wave_dipole) have excess surface charges appearing only when the half waves reach the open ends of the antenna.

Perhaps having two separate groups of charges along the wire limits electromagnetic radiation along the wire by having the electric and magnetic fields uncoupled, which can be a benefit. But, I have not seen in texts that there are two groups of charges.

Can the two half waves moving along the wire been viewed as the two halves of a static open face capacitor moving along the wire?

The pile up at an open ends would be required to form non-static changing concentrations of excess charge, which form a changing electric field between the open ends. The changing electric field from the excess charges forms a coupled magnetic field and the desired radiation.

Comment: What electromagnetic wave are you referring to? Plz be specific.

Comment: Thanks! I've upvoted.

Comment: I have changed the question to better express the problem.